# Java Class for obtaining corresponding Gson json object

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a json object with following representation :

```
{
    text     : "Ed O'Kelley was the man who shot the man who shot Jesse James.",
    entities : [
        ['T1', 'Person', [[0, 11]]],
        ['T2', 'Person', [[20, 23]]],
        ['T3', 'Person', [[37, 40]]],
        ['T4', 'Person', [[50, 61]]],
    ], };
```

I need to create a Java Class that can be used to create JSON with above structure using Gson.

This is what I currently have:

```
public class DocData
{
    private String text;

    private List<List<String>> entities;

    public DocData(final String text, final List<List<String>> entities)
    {
        this.text = text;
        this.entities = entities;
    }

    public List<List<String>> getEntities()
    {
        return entities;
    }
}
```

Above class works for serializing `text` field but I am not sure what datatype I need to use for `entities` so that it creates an array of array of triplets with form `"['T1', 'Person', [[0, 11]]]"`.

Comment: Do you must use "array of array of triplets"? What is wrong with current approach (except that it is not `List<SomeWrapperClass>`)?

Comment: this can help http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: @Pshemo I can use any alternate data-structure which works in this case. Using a WrapperClass introduced another key in json representation like :    entities : [
      "wrapperClass":  ['T1', 'Person', [[0, 11]]] ]};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is fine for the `Json` provided.

however:

The `entities` is a mix of types.

each `entity` in `entities` is an `Array`.

There are 3 element in an `entity`: `String`, `String` and `Array`

This is not the recommended way. i would suggest to use:

```
{
    "text": "Ed O'Kelley was the man who shot the man who shot Jesse James.",
    "entities": [
        {
            "field_name_1": "T1",
            "field_name_2": "Person",
            "field_name_3": [
                [
                    0,
                    11
                ]
            ]
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

in this case you will have 2 `Pojo`'s:

```
public class DocData
{
    private String text;

    private List<Entity> entities;

    public DocData(final String text, final List<Entity> entities)
    {
        this.text = text;
        this.entities = entities;
    }

    public List<Entity> getEntities()
    {
        return entities;
    }
}


public class Entity
{
    private String field_name_1;

    private String field_name_2;

    private List<List<Integer>> field_name_3;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't change the structure of JSON since it is a fixed format JSON expected by a third party tool. I have tried using the POJO Entity but no luck.

Comment: make sure to check the `JSON` and not the `JSONschema`, also check `Gson`